# C snprintf specify user home directory

Tags: c, file, printf, home-directory

I use `snprintf` to write formatted data to disk, but I have one problem, how do I save it to the user's home directory?

```
 snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s_%s.sho", client, id);
```

Comment: Which operating system you're asking for?

Comment: @datenwolf: RHEL/CentOS Linux, macOS, COS Cray.

Comment: BTW, you don't use `snprintf` to write data, you use it to build a file path.

Comment: Yes sorry I did not speak that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux and POSIX systems the home directory is *often* from the `HOME` environment variable. So you might code

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s/%s_%s.sho", 
         getenv("HOME"), client, id);
```

Pedantically the [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) could fail (or be wrong). But that rarely happens. See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).

(You might check, and or use [getpwuid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) with [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html)...)

With [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executables things could become interestingly complex. You would need to define more precisely what the home is, and code appropriately (this is left as an exercise).

Comment: *Pedantically the getenv(3) could fail (or be wrong). But that rarely happens. See environ(7).*  I was working on my answer when you posted that...

Answer (score 3):

The user controls his environment - so the `HOME` environment variable may not be correct or it may not even be set.

Use [`getuid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getuid.3p.html) and [`getpwuid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3p.html) to get the user's home directory as specified by your system:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid( getuid() );

/* need to duplicate the string - we don't know
   what pw_dir points to */
const char *homeDir = strdup( pwd->pw_dir );
```

Error checking is left as an exercise...

Comment: What if more than one user though?

Comment: @YoshiMiro *What if more than one user though?* How?  UIDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getenv(3)` to query the value of the `HOME` environment variable. For example, this prints my home directory:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", getenv("HOME"));
    return 0;
}
```

You can set your variable `filename` to the return value, and then write whatever data you want there.

This should work on any Unix-like system, including Linux, macOS, BSD, and probably many more.