# Using execvp or execlp with a flag?

Tags: c, linux, file-link

I'm trying to write a C program to soft-link 2 files on Unix. In Unix, this command would be:

```
ln -s oldfile newlink
```

So I wrote a code to create a `char *` array of the arguments like so:

```
char *args[4];
args[0] = "ln";
args[1] = "-s";
args[2] = argv[2]; //argv[2] is the name of the old file
args[3] = argv[3]; //argv[3] is the name of the new soft link file


execvp(args[0], args);
```

But the -s flag is not read by the Linux processor. How can I rewrite this in a way that it will handle the -s flag? I tried to do it with `execlp` as well:

```
execlp(args[0], args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], NULL);
```

But that also does not work. What am I doing wrong in these lines?

EDIT: I have also attempted the symlink() command, but I don't think my version of linux supports it, unless I am wrong and there is a flaw in my code:

```
char *args[4];
args[0] = "symlink";
args[1] = argv[2];
args[2] = argv[3];
args[3] = NULL;



execvp(args[0], args);
```

Comment: For `execvp()`, you need a final NULL pointer — so you need `char *args[5];` and `args[4] = NULL;` (or `= 0`).  The `execlp()` is almost OK; strictly, you're supposed to use `(char *)NULL` for the last argument.  This might matter on a 64-bit machine where the system provides `#define NULL 0` with no other type.  That's a valid null pointer — but only in contexts where it is known that a null pointer is required, and the argument list to `execlp()` isn't one of those contexts.

Comment: How do you know it isn't read?

Comment: Notice that `symlink` is *not* a command (available in your shell). It is a system call.

Comment: No: it was suggested that you use the `symlink()` system call.  `if (symlink(argv[2], argv[3]) != 0) { …report error… }`.

Answer (score 2):

> write a C code to soft-link 2 files on linux

For that specific purpose, you don't need to start a `/bin/ln` process in your C code. You should instead use the [symlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html) system call (which would be used by the `ln` process); this is simpler and much faster. Don't forget to check its success. Notice that `symlink` is a [*system call*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (that even old Linux kernels should have) available as a *C function*, not a command (so indeed you cannot run any <strike>`symlink`</strike> *command* or [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) in your shell). As documented, you need to `#include <unistd.h>` in your C source file. Read also [symlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html).

#### using the `symlink` system call

For example, to do the equivalent of `ln -s ~/somefile /tmp` you would first compute the path (e.g. using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)...) corresponding to `~/somefile` (by [using `getenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561948/841108) ...):

```
char* somefilepath = "somefile";
char oldpathbuf[256];
snprintf(oldpathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), "%s/%s", getenv("HOME"), somefilepath);
/// missing detecting and handling of errors in above
```

<sup>(and I leave you to handle all the error cases, including lack of space for `snprintf`, and they are important!)</sup>

Then you need to compute the path of the new link (you cannot use `symlink` system call on directories):

```
 char newpathbuf[256];
 snprintf(newpathbuf, sizeof(newpathbuf), "/tmp/%s", somefilepath);
```

<sup>(again, handle the errors, and think what would happen if `somefilepath` starts with `../`)</sup>

At last, do the system call but check against failure:

```
 if (symlink(newpathbuf, oldpathbuf)) {
   perror("symlink");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

#### executing the `/bin/ln` program

If you insist (wrongly IMHO) on using the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall on `/bin/ln` or some [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) function (which would call `execve`), be sure to explicitly add a `NULL` pointer. BTW on success these `exec` functions don't return, so you probably need to call [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) before and to use [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) after.

Be aware that `execvp` uses the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). So passing just `ln` to it might run (if your user has a weird `$PATH` setting) something else than `/bin/ln` (that file path is specified in the [Linux FHS](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/fhs) and in POSIX) with some unexpected side-effect. But see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).

> the -s flag is not read by the Linux processor

There is no "Linux processor" involved. The `-s` flag is handled by the `/bin/ln` [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) program (whose `main` function gets the expanded program arguments, and which then calls the `symlink` system call). You need to understand more the role of unix shells and what [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) is and how a command is [*expanded*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) by the shell.

#### useful references to read

I recommend reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and the [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man page.

You probably should read more about [Operating Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and understand the difference between commands and system calls and the role of any [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). I recommend reading the freely available [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: I've edited the question- I don't think my (my University's) version of linux (a very old one) is able to execute the symlink() command. Is there a way to do this with the execlp or execvp?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your Linux has the `symlink` syscall. AFAIK it was available even in 1993 Linux kernels and probably even in the first one. You basically can't have a Unix system without it (because it is needed to *implement* the `/bin/ln` command)

Comment: [Here is what I get when I attempt it in the command line.](http://i.imgur.com/qA6tMSE.png) It is an old version of Unix (my apologies) and I don't believe it is included.

Comment: I did explain that `symlink` is a system call, not a command.

Comment: Which 'old version of Unix' are you using, @JohnStawket?  It would have to be very old (20 years or more) and one of the staider variants even then.  POSIX required `symlink()` as a system call from sometime in the 90s. POSIX 1990 did not mandate symbolic links — I checked my paper copy of that standard; POSIX 1997 did.  I'm not sure if there was an intermediate version.

Comment: @JohnStawket: Where did you got the (wrong) impression that `symlink` is a command? You look confused, and I never wrote that, and the links I have provided don't state anything similar. It is a *system call* (you need to understand what these are) and you can call it as a C function (but I won't work in your shell).

Comment: My apologies, I am a novice at C and linux. However, I did attempt it (my sample code is edited into the original post). Did i implement it incorrectly? When I execute the function, no soft link file is created. Is it necessary that I use fork() and wait()?

Comment: Yes, you are confused. Take several days to read the links I gave and both *Advanced Linux Programming* and *Operating system : three easy pieces*; they are freely available books that you need to read (and that takes several days). If you insist on using some `exec` you'll better understand how to use `fork` & `waitpid`

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have time as this assignment is due in a few days, and this is the last piece I need. If you could examine my attempt to call symlink() too see if it is incorrect, any help is appreciated.  and @jonathan-leffler I am running  Solaris 10 s10s_u6wos_07b SPARC

Comment: @JohnStawket: Solaris 10 has the `symlink()` system call.  Very few if any systems have a `symlink` command — it is not standard and the `ln -s` command suffices.