# How to call python from c++

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi

I'm Python new comer. I tried to call a python script from c++ like this (in Raspberry Pi).

```
std::string pythonCommand = "python Callee.py \""+a+"\" "+b;
int res = system(pythonCommand.c_str());
```

after running I got this.

```
python: can't open file 'Callee.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But I can run Callee.py with command line successfully and both file stored in same directory.

What was I missing ?

Comment: Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Comment: Provinding the path worked for me

Comment: Isn't it better to link against python and use native interpreter instead of going through system?

Comment: I dun no how to do that I'm very new in python.

Answer (score 3):

You probably are running the python interpreter (and your `python Callee.py` command) in some strange directory (i.e. in some other directory than what you are expecting).

You could use [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) before your call to [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) to find out your current working directory.

You might use the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call (before calling `system`) to change the directory to something appropriate. See perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561948/841108).

I recommend also reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Read also about [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/); but if you need to embed some interpreter consider also [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile) & [Lua](http://lua.org/).

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
system("/work/test/pythonscript.sh")
```

and define inside this script how your python script is executed/called.

This way you dont trip over format errors (c_string() and "\r" or OS-dependent line endings)

Comment: Will only work if that `/work/test/pythonscript.sh` file is executable and starts with appropriate shebang

Comment: You are right. But because OP mentioned a `Callee.py` script, I think this problem has already been concerned. It also works only if you run it on a linux machine, for other OS you need to edit the path correctly