# Use Python Traci From SUMO to run with OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm a beginner in Omnet++ & SUMO. I have successfully created my python script using the Traci library from SUMO. So, now I am currently trying to run my python script inside OMNET++ but I do not have any idea on how to do it. Can anyone guide me regarding this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is too broad for SO. You're asking us to write a tutorial which is off-topic. Instead identify a specific problem and ask about that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

pybind11 makes it easy to call python constructs in c++. I did install pybind11 in debian and successfuly invoked a python script. [How to use pybind11 in omnet++ projects like veins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71013592/7215379)
This is another way of calling python from c++.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ uses C++ so you should look for an answer to the question: "How to call Python script from C++". There are many answers to this question, for example [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155740/how-to-call-python-from-c).
Moreover, if you are beginner in `OMNeT++`, I strongly suggest to look at [Tic Toc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part1/) to understand NED and C++ API.